# How to print a line from a file if it contains a string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying print a line which has string 'usb' in it. I am using python 2.7.

The following is my code:

```
>>> fd=open('abc.text', 'r')
>>> for line in fd.readlines():
...     print line
...
this is to test

python i/o

and other such stuff

btw what is usb

Usb is something

to look forward to..

>>> for line in fd.readlines():
...     if 'usb' in line:
...         print line
...
>>>
```

Comment: Please don't put an image of text in your question. Please put the actual text itself. Please copy-paste any examples into a code block in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you loop through the lines using `fd.readlines()` python is at the end of the file. When you call it again there are no lines to read. To get back to the start of the file, use `fd.seek(0)` and then you can use `fd.readlines()` again.